# Java regular expression to replace single letters with white spaces on either side with a space

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone help me with a regular expression to replace all the single letters with spaces. 
Example:

```
 input: "this is a t f with u f array"
output: "this is       with     array".
```

my regular expression is `replaceAll("(\\s+[a-z]\\s+)"," ");`
But its works as follows:

```
  input: "this is a t f with u f array"
 output: "this is   t f with   f array".
```

Comment: Are you sure the output of your test isn't `this is t with f array`?

Comment: A single letter in a Java regex is `\pL`, not `[a-z]`.  `[a-z]` is so nasty as to cause a **really bad code smell** wherever it occurs.  And don’t even get me started on normalization.

Comment: You can’t use `\s` for whitespace in Java.  It’s broken.  Watch what happens when you have U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE in your data.

Answer (score 6):

The problem occurs because of the way replaceAll works. What happens is after each time it replaces a section it starts looking after the section it matched, for example when your pattern runs you get the result

```
this is t with f array
```

What is happening internally is:

1. match pattern against "this is a t f with u f array"
2. match found at " t "
3. replace with " ".
4. Begin matching **after** last match ("f with u f array")
5. Note "f " does not match because there is no leading space.

What you need use is a trick called "zero-width positive lookahead" If you use the pattern:

```
(\\s+[a-z](?=\\s))
```

The second space says "try to match, but don't actually count it as part of the match". So when the next match occurs it will be able to use that space as part of its match.

You will also need to replace with the empty string, since the trailing space is not removed i.e.

```
"this is a t f with u f array".replaceAll("(\\s+[a-z](?=\\s))","")
```

Comment: +1 for explanation, however your regex would lead to double spaces since the trailing space in a group of matches would not get replaced.

Comment: @tchrist I am interested to know what you don't like about the proposed solution (besides the trailing space issue Shaded already pointed out)

Comment: The original requirement was "replace all single letters with space" which this will do. If the requirement was "replace all single letters and their surrounding spaces with a single space" this would also work, you'd just replace it with `""`

Comment: tchrist is complaining about using `[a-z]` since that only matches ... well, a-z

Comment: @Brian Roach, Indeed that would work for the given example, the only caveat would be if the end of the match group was multiple spaces. However, you're absolutely right about the original requirements. :D

Comment: @Brian, thanks for pointing that out, I had it when I was double checking my pattern, but forgot to mention it, edited to include.

Answer (score 2):

You can try word [boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
"this is a t f with u f array".replaceAll("\\b[a-z]\\b"," ")
```

Comment: You can’t use `\b` in Java: it’s broken.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... maybe because when the " a " is found and replaced in "... a t f ..", the matcher looks at the following character, wich is 't' (the space is already consumed). But then again I'd expect the output to be "this is t with f array".

Try using `replaceAll("((\s+[a-z])*\s+)"," ")` instead. But it has the (unwanted?) side effect that any length of whitespace will be reduced to a single space.

Comment: No, not any length of whitespace.  It doesn’t work on Unicode, just on 50-year-old ASCII.

Comment: So, is that a real world problem or just an academic example? I have not yet seen any text file where \s didn't work for whitespace in practice.

Comment: It is a **VERY** real-world problem.  In the PubMed Open Access corpus, a very large and very important collection, the second most frequent non-ASCII character is U+00A0, NO-BREAK SPACE.  Java is useless here.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks for pointing that out. On the other hand, one could argue that there could be reasons for not including non-breaking spaces. But at least it should be documented in the description of \s in Oracles documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working on your test :

```
(\s+[a-z](\s[a-z])*\s+)
```

Comment: That needs a *tête-à-tête* treatment.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll("\\b[a-z]\\b", " ");`

will output

```
this is       with     array
```

The problem is in how the replaceAll approaches things. `\\s[a-z]\\s` matches

> " a "

then moves on to

> "t f with u f array"

which causes it to miss the first `t`

Comment: That wasn't his given input. He supplied `[a-z]`, which works for his input.

Comment: People who supply `[a-z]` are usually asking the wrong question.  Just because they ask the wrong question doesn’t mean you should give them the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use word boundary:-

```
    String s = "this is a t f with u f array";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\b\\w\\b\\s+", "");
    System.out.println(s); // this is with array
```

Comment: That does not work on real data.  Java has broken `\b`.  There are data for which `\b\w+\b` tests false at all points even though it has wordchars in it.  You must not use `\b` in Java.  Nor really `\w` either, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

String a = "this is a t f with u f array";

a = a.replaceAll("(\s\p{Alpha}(?=\s))+((?=\s)\s)", " ");

Zero width positive lookahead followed by a match of the trailing space in a capture group produces what you're looking for:

this is with array

Comment: Good try, but Java’s implementation of `\p{Alpha}` and `\s` are both  [broken according to the standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).  You’ll have to use `\pL` for a letter (which is not the same as an alphabetic), and for whitespace, you’ll have to do it the hard way via enumeration.  Java’s regexes are not even Level 1 compliant with the Unicode Standard, which is the minimal function necessary for working with trans-ASCII text.

Comment: replacing \p{Alpha} and \s with enumerations is less than optimal; besides it does not change the general solution which is to use zero width positive look ahead. java compliance with a standard doesn't mean much unless you are using data which causes java to exhibit it's deficiency. if the solution works for the domain of the data that a person is interested in, then the solution is valid.  though it would be nice to say that a solution would work for all possible values in a given domain, it's not likely that it is necessary to work for all possible values in a given domain.

Comment: I try never to write ASCII-only patterns.  And the original problem said  letter.  That cries out for `\pL`.